# Karma: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a method (refreshMemberList()) that contains a subscribe, but when I run the tests I get this error from Karma. Can anyone tell me what is going on? Thank you very much in advance, such a great community you are :D

Jasmine spec list failure:

```
    MemberListComponent > refreshMemberList refreshes members list
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

member-list.component.ts:

```
describe('MemberListComponent', () => {
  let component: MemberListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MemberListComponent>;
  let mockMemberListService: jasmine.SpyObj<MemberListService>;
  let modalService: NgbModal;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    mockMemberListService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getMembers']);
    mockMemberListService.getMembers.and.returnValue(memberMockObject.fakeMemberListJSON);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MemberListService,
          useValue: mockMemberListService,
        }
      ],
      declarations: [MemberListComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    modalService = TestBed.get(NgbModal);
  });

  it('refreshMemberList refreshes members list', () => {
    component.refreshMemberList(memberMockObject.dataMemberMap);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.members).toEqual(memberMockObject.fakeMembers);
  });


});
```

member-list.component.ts:

```
export class MemberListComponent implements OnInit {
  public title: String = "Members";
  public showMemberDeletedAlert: Boolean;
  private _memberListService: MemberListService;
  public members: Member[] = []; 
  private dataMemberMap: Map<string, string>;
  public page: number = 0;
  public pageSize: number = 10;
  public collectionSize: number;
  public isLoading: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    memberListService: MemberListService,
    private _modalService: NgbModal
  ) {
    this._memberListService = memberListService;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(history.state.type==="delete")
      this.showDeletedAlert()
    this.dataMemberMap =  new Map([
      ["name", ""],
      ["role", ""],
      ["skill", ""],
      ["skillLevel", ""],
      ["language", ""],
      ["languageLevel", ""]
      ]);
    this.retrieveMemberList();
  }

  retrieveMemberList(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._memberListService.getMembers(this.dataMemberMap!, this.page, this.pageSize).subscribe((data) => {
      this.members = data.memberList;
      this.collectionSize = data.totalPages * this.pageSize;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  refreshMemberList(dataMemberMap: Map<string, string>): void {
    this.dataMemberMap = dataMemberMap;
    this.retrieveMemberList();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a class property of type `MemberListService`? Just use the dependency injection as

```js
constructor(private memberListService: MemberListService) {}
```

Then just use it as:

```js
...
this.memberListService.getMembers(...);
```

Also, you have all this logic been triggered right from the beginning, in your `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, which is fine; the first test you should have for this component should be this one:

```js
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This test (which is the first test by default) verifies the successful creation of your component, so any logic within your `ngOnInit` will be tested, some of this logic is calling your `getMembers` service function sending 3 parameters, maybe some or all of those are `undefined`?

Also, I don't know what `memberMockObject` is in your test file, so for setting the return type, I would say use `of` from rxjs to create an `observable`:

```js
mockMemberListService.getMembers
  .and.returnValue(of(yourDesiredValueHere));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined, so can't read the subscribe property, since you want this (_memberListService) to be private, you can just use (memberListService) on the constructor as private and do not use _memberListService, it'd something like

```
  constructor(
    private memberListService: MemberListService,
    private _modalService: NgbModal
  ) {}
```

and when you call getMembers you can just use `this.memberListService.getMembers(...`

Comment: This does not solve the original problem that `.subscribe` expects an `Observable<ProbablyJson>` but only receives `ProbablyJson`.